# How to downsample all the videos in a folder?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I had asked this question before, I have a solution using the *moviepy* library. But, this is taking a lot of time.
I know that when I use ffmpeg via the terminal, the down sampling process is much faster.

```
command = (
            f"ffmpeg -n -i {'inputvideo_path'} -filter:v "
            f"scale={width}:{height} {{}}-c:a copy {output_path}"
        )
```

I am looking for the implementation in ffmeg library

Comment: Why don't you try to use something like this library: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) if you want to do execute terminal commands from python script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the python `os` library with your command. `os.listdir()` lists the files and `os.system()` executes your command.

```py
import os

for inputvideo_path in os.listdir():
  os.system(command)
```